# Laravel - Form value is not updating

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have a **projects** table with the value of the following column:

```
id_project   name           website         country_id  currency_id  timezone_id
==========.  ====           =======         ==========. ===========. ===========
1            project name.  www.yahoo.com.  10          8            10
```

I have form with above fields. Now, when I press submit I can see I can get updating form fields data using:

```
dd($request);
```

But using this code the database is not updating:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //dd($request); // It's showing me updated form fields value

    $project = Project::where('id_project', $id)->first();
    $project->name = $request->name;
    $project->country_id = $request->country;
    $project->currency_id = $request->currency;
    $project->timezone_id = $request->timezone;
    $project->website = $request->website;
    $project->save();

    return response()->json($project, 200);
}
```

**Update:**

Strange things. If I run this it's not updateing

```
$project = Project::where('id_project', $id)->update(['name' => $request->name ]);
```

But If I manually add the value:

```
$project = Project::where('id_project', $id)->update(['name' => 'example data' ]);
```

It's updating database.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Please, make sure your `$id` variable has any value in it. Also you could try converting this into DB Query Builder

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    DB::table('projects')->where('id_project', $id)->update([
         'name' => $request->name,
         'country_id' => $request->country,
         'currency_id' => $request->currency,
         'timezone_id' => $request->timezone,
         'website' => $request->website
    ]);
}
```

But first check if `dd($id)` and `dd($request->all())` has any values.

Comment: No, it's not updating...

Comment: what is the output of `dd($request->all(), $id);`?

Comment: its showing data: https://prnt.sc/vCmB0V44BJfn

Comment: Do this `public function update(Request $request, $id) { dd($request->all(), $id); }` and submit the form. Screenshot the output.

Comment: It seems showing data also: https://prnt.sc/iCWsa0YgLbTQ

Comment: Everything seems alright. Try to see the output of the query result. `dd(DB::table('projects')->where('id_project', $id)->update(['name' => $request->name,'country_id' => $request->country,'currency_id' => $request->currency,'timezone_id' => $request->timezone,'website' => $request->website]))`. And please make sure you're actually hitting the right database.

Comment: It's showing me 1.

Comment: `1 = TRUE`, `0 = FALSE`. Everything is alright then... I'm asking again - are you sure you are hitting the right database? Do you have multiple database connections?

Comment: Yes, I am sure because If I run this `DB::table('projects')->where('id_project', $id)->update([
            'name' => 'manually entered'
       ]);` it's successfully updating.

Comment: Would you please come to chat discussion?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to do that. Anyway, try to set in the `Project` model this `Protected $primaryKey = "id_project";`

Comment: It's already set

Answer (score 0):

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $project = Project::find($id);
    $project->name = $request->name;
    $project->country_id = $request->country;
    $project->currency_id = $request->currency;
    $project->timezone_id = $request->timezone;
    $project->website = $request->website;
    $project->save();
}
```

Try this!

Comment: No luck Nitin :(

Comment: What the form method? 

    @csrf
    @method('PUT')

Comment: I don't understand. If I manually entered the value it's updating but if I use $request then it's not.

Comment: first check if project is getting by id? 

dd($project);

Comment: Yes, I did and it's getting id + other updated parms

Comment: no, after this $project = Project::where('id_project', $id)->first(); then add dd($project);

Comment: Yes, it's getting data.

Comment: I mean dd is showing the data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

the best practice in laravel to update records it´s:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $project = Project::find($id);
    $project->name = $request->name;
    $project->country_id = $request->country;
    $project->currency_id = $request->currency;
    $project->timezone_id = $request->timezone;
    $project->website = $request->website;
    $project->save();
}
```

also yo can use this:

```
$data = array(
                'compania_id'        => $request->get("compania"),
                'nombre_tratamiento' => $request->get("nombre_tratamiento"),
                'precio_sesion'      => $request->get("precio_sesion"),
            );
            $tratamiento = TreatmentCompany::find($request->get("cod_tratamiento"));

            $result = $tratamiento->update($data);

            return $result;
```

Comment: Why the manualy entry is working instead of `$request` ?

Comment: @Shibbir i think that your request it´s empty you should check that your request it´s ok, with dd() or $request->name; with echo. I recommend you that instead of use $request->option use $request->get('option') check that your name input in html have this name